# SSH Login with expect and while / loop

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh, while-loop, expect

I need to login to 50 different servers and run a script with expect

how can i implement a loop with expect?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn bash -c "ssh -tt $user@$ip < /root/examplescript.sh"
expect "*assword:"
send "$password\r"
interact
```

output listserver.txt

```
user password ip
user password ip
user password ip
user password ip
user password ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep the hosts etc. list in a separate file, take a look at the answer Andreas Louv links to.  If you do not, you could just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

foreach {user password ip} {
    user1 password1 ip1
    user2 password2 ip2
    user3 password3 ip3
    user4 password4 ip4
} {
    spawn bash -c "ssh -tt $user@$ip < /root/examplescript.sh"
    expect "*assword:"
    send "$password\r"
    interact
}
```